# Yii SOAP Web Service Session ID is reset

Tags: php, web-services, session, soap, yii

I am building a SOAP Web Service with Yii, and I am trying to manage the authentications through the Session ID, but it keeps changing on every request.
This is the code I have written:

```
class MessagingController extends CController {

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $user = User::model()->find('username=:username AND password=:password', array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
       if($user) {
            $session = new Session();
            $session->id = Yii::app()->session->sessionID;
            $session->user = $user->id;
            $session->start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',  time());
            $session->duration = $this->sessionDuration; //Session duration is 1hr.`

            return $session->save() ? 
              $this->generateResponse(0, 'Session initiated successfully.', array('SessionId' => $session->id, 'Timestamp' => $session->start, 'Duration' => $session->duration)) : generateResponse(-1, 'Server error. #S', null);
        }
    return $this->generateResponse(-1, 'Unknown User. #UU', null);
}
```

}

Config File:
'session' => array(
            'autoStart' => true,
            'timeout' => 1440,
            'cookieMode' => 'allow',
        ),

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to specify in your SoapServer that the session should be persistent.

http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.setpersistence.php

Comment: I can't figure out where it goes :( I am just getting started with Yii and SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Since soap requests are stateless, each request goes without cookies and as such PHP by default will always create new cookie when starting new session. If you want to use the same session on SoapServer side across multiple client requests, you should set two things:

- **first** ensure that you always send the same session cookie from your requesting server (via SoapClient). This is done by __setCookie():

  $soapClient->__setCookie('PHPSESSID', $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
- **second** - as stated above - set soapserver persistence:

  $soapServer->setPersistence(SOAP_PERSISTENCE_SESSION);